# Remove question mark at the end of the URL

Tags: html, forms, url

```
<form action="sample.php" method="get">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

After click on submit, there will open a new page with URL: sample.php?
I want to open this new page without question mark (?). Is there any way to do this? P.S. Firefox doesn't add this mark. Only chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use form method as post

```
<form action="sample.php"     method="post">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Perfect. @kannan Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `POST` request, like this: `method="post"`

there is no solution else

```
<form action="sample.php" method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for help @Nabi